# How to read all avaiable data from a Serial stream and then stop

Tags: arduino-uno, softwareserial

I am trying to read data from the Serial port in my Arduino, store it in a buffer and when all the data has been read stop reading and then start using the data (the talkMIDI() function). The Arduino succesfully some bytes from Serial but not all of them and then hangs without stopping before the end.

```
void loop() {
  if (!stop) 
  {
    char in = Serial.read();
    if (in != -1)
    {
      buffer[pos] = in;
      pos++;
      Serial.write("read");
      Serial.print(pos);
      Serial.print("\r\n");
    }
    if (in == 126)
    {
      stop = 1;
      Serial.write("STOP");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if (cursor < pos)
    {
      talkMIDI (buffer[cursor], buffer[cursor+1], buffer[cursor+2]);
      cursor = cursor+3;
      delay(500);
    }
  }
}
```

After manually sending a 126 value (~) character, I get a "STOP" response on the Serial line but Arduino doesn't start executing the code from the else branch (the talkMIDI() part -- the function doesn't even get called once).

Comment: Where do you declare stop? Maybe it's not the same stop at the top of the loop.

Comment: stop is declared globally at the beginning.

Comment: Then it must be the cursor < pos test.

Comment: How do you mean?

Comment: You should read this: http://hacking.majenko.co.uk/reading-serial-on-the-arduino

Comment: Looking at it quickly, if stop is set, then the reason for not executing the code in the else branch would be the expression (cursor < pos). Maybe put a Serial.println in the branch (before the if) to confirm that the else is getting executed.

Comment: Trying to send multiple characters for each received character is not likely to work well unless the characters are sent to the Arduino with substantial delays in between them.